# Send PDF link in email based on radio button selection

Tags: php, email

I am using custom email and form in my wordpress site.

Thing is in form there are 2 radio buttons :

1. English
2. Chinese

Other fields are normal.

I have 2 PDF uploaded to server for both above languages. What I want is to send use PDF link in email based on language selection in form.

I am trying but it is sending always same PDF link.

**Code to check data and send in email :**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['language1'])){
  $clname=$_POST['clname'];
  $clsurname=$_POST['clsurname'];
  $clemail=$_POST['clemail'];
  $radio = $_POST['language1'];
  $fileatt1     = "http://example.com/english.pdf";
  $fileatttype = "application/pdf";
  $fileattname = "newname.pdf"; //name that you want to use to send or you can use the same name

  $headers = 'From: '. $clname .' <'. $clemail .'>' . "\r\n";
  $mail = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = "Testing";


  $message = 'Name:'.$clname.' '.$clsurname.'\n\n
    Email:'.$clemail.'\n\n Radiovalue:'.$radio.'\n'. $fileatt;

  wp_mail($mail,$subject,$message,$headers);
            $emailsent= true;
}
```

**Form Code**

```
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <form class="text-center" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

    <div class="col-md-6">
       <p class="tns">First Name *:</p>
       <input type="text" name="clname" placeholder="First Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="tns">Last Name *:</p>
        <input type="text" name="clsurname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
        <input type="radio" name="language1" value="English">English 
        <input type="radio" name="language2" value="Chinese">Chinese </div>

      </div>

      <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="overflow-hidden">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">


      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have tried to put another PDF link in ELSE condition but that is not working. I have also tried by put 2 different if conditions but that is also not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same `name` attribute for your 2 radio inputs.  So let's say that name is `language`. If `language` is set, you have 2 options represented by `value`, either `English` or `Chinese`.

In the code you posted, that is mainly your problem. You set your `$radio` variable to be `$_POST['language1']` but `$_POST['language1']` will **ALWAYS** be `English` because the `Chinese` value is set by `$_POST['language2']`

in your form markup, change your `radio` input `name` values

```
<div class="overflow-hidden">
  <form class="text-center" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="tns">First Name *:</p>
      <input type="text" name="clname" placeholder="First Name" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p class="tns">Last Name *:</p>
      <input type="text" name="clsurname" placeholder="Last Name" required />
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="English">English 
      <input type="radio" name="language" value="Chinese">Chinese
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="overflow-hidden">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

In your PHP:

- Change references of `language1` to `language`
- Use [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to set `$fileatt`. If `$radio` is `English` output English url to file. Output Chinese url otherwise.

.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['language'])){

  $radio       = $_POST['language'];
  $fileatt     = 'English' == $radio ? "http://example.com/english.pdf" : "http://example.com/chinese.pdf" ;
  $fileatttype = "application/pdf";


  $headers = 'From:' . $_POST['clname'] . ' <'. $_POST['clemail'] .'>' . "\r\n";
  $mail = get_option('admin_email');
  $subject = "Testing";


  $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['clname'] . ' ' . $_POST['clsurname'] .'\n\n
  Email:'.$_POST['clemail'].'\n\n Radiovalue:' . $radio . '\n'. $fileatt;

  wp_mail($mail,$subject,$message,$headers);
  $emailsent= true;
}
```